# Segue of Table cell in a tab and navtigation view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've just recently started learning about Xcode and the swift language. To get myself familiarise with them I'm trying to build a simple app with what I've learnt so far. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udq7x.png)

The screenshot shows what I want to achieve. VC1 and VC2 are both a navigation + tab VC. When the user taps on the "Preset" button on the navigation bar of VC1, the screen will switch to VC2 which has a table with different preset values. What I did was to create an action segue (show) from the "preset" button to VC2. All good so far.

This is what I want to do but couldn't figure a way to do it: At the table at VC2, when the user click on any row, he will be brought back to VC1 and the value in the selected row is being inserted into a textfield in VC1.

What I had tried to do was to create an action segue (show) from the table cell to VC1. But by doing so, the navigation bar and tab bar on VC1 and VC2 has disappeared [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZ7D.png)

Is what I'm trying to do achievable? if yes, what did i do wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use storyboards with an IBAction to return to the previous view controller, such as

```
@IBAction func userDidSelectTableCell() {
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

But in your case I think your after a unwind segue, I've not used one but you can read more about them at this following link https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you need to use a `unwind segue`. In order to achieve this, you firstly need to declare a global variable in your VC2 class which stores the value of the selected row. You can use the `didSelectRow` method for that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedCell = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifier", sender: self)
    }
```

you need to add a `@IBAction` method in you VC1 class.

```
@IBAction func unwindtoVC1(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
   if let sourceVC = sender.source as? YourTableViewController {
            yourTextFiled.text = sourceVC.selectedCell
        }
}
```

In you storyboard, in VC2, Control+drag-drop from viewController to Exit portion to create a segue. 
[image]

From the pop-up that comes, select the `unwindtoVC1` method.

Now, select the segue and in the attributes inspector, give it any identifier.
[image]

Use this identifier in your VC2 class, in the `didSelectRow` method, in the `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifier", sender: self)`

Hope this helps.